# How do I change the bad action I selected as default on USB stick insertion?

Tags: usb

I inserted my smartphone in my laptop with a usb cable, and I wrongly checked the "Set this action as default" (or "Remember this action", I don't remember the exact sentence) after I selected a bad action (Open folder) because it is the system partition of the smartphone. I do I revert this action so that ubuntu ask me again what to do and I can instruct him to always do nothing?
I just want to auto open the data partition.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention what version of Ubuntu you are using.

See if the system menu/indicator (button in the top-right corner) has an *About this computer* item (or something like that).
If yes, press it. That's where you can do what you are asking.

If not, then you'll have to search in the System Preferences for those option (I don't remember where they were in older Ubuntu versions).

Comment: Thank Bruno, I use Raring (13.04) with Unity and I never noticed the System Details applet in System Settings does feature these controls (Removable Media section). Unfortunately both partitions in my smartphone are detected as digital audio devices, and as the actions controls rely on device type, I couldn't set a specific action for the data partition. I thought the behaviour was based on something like UUID... fortunately, the data partition is also detected as a picture device... so in the end I **could** obtain the behaviour I whished (auto-open in files browser data partition only) :)))